# Add new dependency

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I added the new dependency via this command:

[install asyncawait --save](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/01/20/support-for-package-json-in-azure-mobile-services.aspx)

It installed perfectly fine but when I pushed it I got the following result:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree commit -q -F /var/folders/7v/9yb72t8s2_b52zgfyrqdg1ym0000gn/T/SourceTreeTemp.TCJGhh 


git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags --set-upstream origin master:master 
Pushing to 
POST git-receive-pack (897714 bytes)
remote: Updating branch 'master'.        
remote: Updating submodules.        
remote: Preparing deployment for commit id '188de23ecf'.        
remote: Running custom deployment command...        
remote: Running deployment command...        
remote: Handling Basic Web Site deployment.        
remote: KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository\service' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\config\scripts'        
remote: Copying file: 'package.json'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\.npmignore'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\async.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\asyncawait.njsproj'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\asyncawait.sln'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\await.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\changelog.md'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\gulpfile.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\index.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\LICENSE'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\package.json'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\README.md'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\benchmark.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\mockfs.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\README.md'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\countFiles\countFiles-async.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\countFiles\countFiles-asyncawait.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\countFiles\countFiles-bluebird.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\countFiles\countFiles-callbacks.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\countFiles\countFiles-co.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\countFiles\countFiles-synchronous.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\fibonacci\fibonacci-async.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\fibonacci\fibonacci-asyncawait.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\fibonacci\fibonacci-bluebird.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\fibonacci\fibonacci-callbacks.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\fibonacci\fibonacci-co.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\fibonacci\fibonacci-synchronous.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\largest\largest-async.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\largest\largest-asyncawait-iterators.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\largest\largest-asyncawait.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\largest\largest-bluebird.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\largest\largest-callbacks.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\largest\largest-co.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\comparison\largest\largest-synchronous.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\examples\asyncMod.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\examples\awaitTop.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\examples\basic.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\examples\countFiles.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\examples\descendentFilePaths.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\examples\examples.njsproj'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\examples\interleaved.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\examples\iteration.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\examples\package.json'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\examples\parallel.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\node_modules\bluebird\LICENSE'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\node_modules\bluebird\package.json'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\node_modules\bluebird\README.md'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\node_modules\bluebird\js\browser\bluebird.js'        
remote: Copying file: 'node_modules\asyncawait\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\any.js'        
remote: Omitting next output lines...        
remote: Looking for app.js/server.js under site root.        
remote: Missing server.js/app.js files, web.config is not generated        
remote: Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.6.17, 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.8.27, 0.8.28, 0.10.5, 0.10.18, 0.10.21, 0.10.24, 0.10.26, 0.10.28, 0.10.29, 0.10.31, 0.10.32.        
remote: Selected node.js version 0.10.32. Use package.json file to choose a different version.        
remote: Updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\config\scripts\iisnode.yml        
remote: npm WARN package.json urmuv@1.0.0 No repository field.        
remote: npm WARN package.json urmuv@1.0.0 No readme data.        
remote: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/asyncawait        
remote: npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/asyncawait        
remote: npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: asyncawait@'^0.7.4'        
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.        
remote: npm ERR! Valid install targets:        
remote: npm ERR! ["0.5.0","0.5.1","0.5.2","0.5.3","0.5.4","0.6.0","0.6.1","0.7.0","0.7.1","0.7.2","0.7.3","0.7.4"]        
remote: npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\1.2.30\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:719:10)        
remote: npm ERR!     at D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\1.2.30\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:641:10        
remote: npm ERR!     at saved (D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\1.2.30\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:138:7)        
remote: npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)        
remote: npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:        
remote: npm ERR!            
remote: npm ERR! or email it to:        
remote: npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>        
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200        
remote: npm ERR! command "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\0.10.32\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\1.2.30\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--production"        
remote: npm ERR! cwd D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\config\scripts        
remote: npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32        
remote: npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.30        
remote: npm        
remote: 
remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website failed.        
To 
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
   7064159..188de23  master -> master
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'
Completed successfully
```

The only change is made in package.json and node_modules. In package.json:

from  "dependencies": {}, to
   "dependencies": {
     "asyncawait": "^0.7.4"
   },

And node_modules folder now contains the files of asyncawait. Any idea what is the issue and how can I solve it.

Thanks,
Attiqe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have run into a bug where an older version of npm doesn't support the caret (^). For now, you can try the workaround David Ebbo describes in this forum thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/068ef026-f80d-4bf8-9f40-5d1af33a1024/git-deployment-fails-with-npm-error-when-resolving-a-package-version-containing-a-?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview